# Google Calendar - How to Get Multi-Day Events to Show as Blocks of Time

Tags: google-workspace, google-calendar, google

I'm adding multiple blocks of non all-day, multi-day, events for my upcoming Code Fellows classes.

I've found that Google Calendar, in both the week and day view, has no way apparent way of showing these events as anything other than an all-day-styled event.

I want these events to show up as blocks of time for each day they occur, not just as an unhelpful bar at the top of the calendar. Is that possible?
[image]

Comment: Hi.Did you find a solution?